# Azure Service Bus - Unable to close a session manually using Java

Tags: java, azure, session, service, bus

There is an Azure Service Bus Queue with the **session property enabled** *(Requires session = true)*

The consumer is a native Azure Java "client" *(com.azure:azure-messaging-servicebus)*

The problem is that there is no way with this Java client to close the session manually.
As a result, when `maxConcurrentSessions` reached the whole application stop receiving messages until the session lock timeout reached.

So the main question here is: **How can we close a session manually using the Java client?**

---

Might help:

> In this article there is an example how to do it but is on C#. It
> seems that there is a "session" object used to close the
> session. I was not able to reproduce it in the Java client.
>
> https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/ordering-messages-in-azure-service-bus/

Code of the client init:

```
new ServiceBusClientBuilder()
        .connectionString(queueConnectionString)
        .sessionProcessor()
        .queueName(queueName)
        .maxConcurrentSessions(5)
        .maxConcurrentCalls(2)
        .processMessage(this::processMessage)
        .processError(this::processError)
        .maxAutoLockRenewDuration(Duration.ofMinutes(30))
        .disableAutoComplete()
        .buildProcessorClient();
```

Comment: Are these helpful? [QueueSessionTests.java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/3f31d68eed6fbe11516ca3afe3955c8840a6e974/sdk/servicebus/microsoft-azure-servicebus/src/test/java/com/microsoft/azure/servicebus/QueueSessionTests.java) and [SessionHandlerOptions.java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/3f31d68eed6fbe11516ca3afe3955c8840a6e974/sdk/servicebus/microsoft-azure-servicebus/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/servicebus/SessionHandlerOptions.java) and

Comment: [More details about prefetchCount and maxConcurrentSessions in ServiceBusClientBuilder.ServiceBusSessionProcessorClientBuilder Class](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/25293)